# Complicated SQL insert-update with inner select

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have to make a query, which inserts-or-updates in 1 line.

EDIT: I add the *WORKING* SQL query here.

```
    $this->sqlSavePlot = $this->db->prepare(
        "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO plots (id, level, X, Z, name, owner, helpers, denied, biome) VALUES
        ((select id from plots where level = :level AND X = :X AND Z = :Z),
         :level, :X, :Z, :name, :owner, :helpers, :denied, :biome);"
    );
```

Theoretically i want the same stuff in prepared MySQL statements

Currently the mess looks like this:

```
    $this->sqlSavePlot = $this->db->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO plots (`id`, `level`, `X`, `Z`, `name`, `owner`, `helpers`, `denied`, `biome`)
        VALUES(id = (SELECT id FROM plots WHERE level = level AND X = VALUES(X) AND Z = VALUES(Z)), level = ?, X = ?, Z = ?, name = ?, owner = ?, helpers = ?, denied = ?, biome = ?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            id = VALUES(id),
            level = VALUES(level),
            X = VALUES(X),
            Z = VALUES(Z),
            name = VALUES(name),
            owner = VALUES(owner),
            helpers = VALUES(helpers),
            denied = VALUES(denied),
            biome = VALUES(biome);"
    );
```

As you see, quite chaotic.

This is how the database looks like:

[image: The database]

So in theory, if the user executes the **savePlot** function, **several fields are** replaced, like you can see in the PHP code. **"sqlSavePlot" is the query i showed above**

For some deeper explanation some PHP code:

```
    public function savePlot(Plot $plot): bool{
    print "------------------------------------------------------".PHP_EOL;
    $this->db->ping();

    $helpers = implode(',', $plot->helpers);
    $denied = implode(',', $plot->denied);
    if ($plot->id <= 0){
        $stmt = $this->sqlSavePlot;
        $stmt->bind_param('siisssss', $plot->levelName, $plot->X, $plot->Z, $plot->name, $plot->owner, $helpers, $denied, $plot->biome);
    } else{
        $stmt = $this->sqlSavePlotById;
        $stmt->bind_param('isiisssss', $plot->id, $plot->levelName, $plot->X, $plot->Z, $plot->name, $plot->owner, $helpers, $denied, $plot->biome);
    }
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    var_dump($stmt);
    var_dump($result);
    var_dump($plot);
    $this->lastSave = time();

    if ($result === false){
        $this->plugin->getLogger()->error($stmt->error);
        return false;
    }
    $this->cachePlot($plot);
    return true;
}
```

A plot's id can either be -1 if "empty", or have an ID which is fetched from the savePlot function

I know that the messed up part is around the first "Values":

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?, X = ?, Z = ?, name = ?, owner = ?, helpers = ?, denied = ?,
>   biome = ?)
>         ' at line 2

Could someone explain me what i could put instead?

EDIT: as requested, SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `plots` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `level` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `X` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Z` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `owner` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `helpers` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `denied` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `biome` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `XZ` (`X`,`Z`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3609 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Please add info from `SHOW CREATE TABLE plots`. Also explain what you are trying to do. A not working query can't do that for you.

Comment: Added as requested

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more like this:

```
INSERT INTO plots (`id`, `level`, `X`, `Z`, `name`, `owner`, `helpers`, `denied`, `biome`)
    SELECT id, p.level, p.X, p.Z, ?, ?, ?, ?
    FROM plots p
    WHERE p.level = ? AND X = ? AND Z = ?
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE name = VALUES(name),
               owner = VALUES(owner),
               helpers = VALUES(helpers),
               denied = VALUES(denied),
               biome = VALUES(biome);
```

You need to be careful about the order of the arguments.  I am guessing that `id` is the primary key and `(X, Z, level)` is declared as unique (how you identify duplicates).  You only specify that you want to change name in the event of a collision, but this sets all the values (as in your version).

Comment: I added some more information to my question, for example the SQL query i want to translate to mysql and the database look.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed up my Query with the answer provided by [@Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)

Turns out i even had a logical issue.. i mixed up the "saveByID" and "saveByXZ"..

```
public function savePlot(Plot $plot): bool{
    $this->db->ping();
    $helpers = implode(',', $plot->helpers);
    $denied = implode(',', $plot->denied);

    if ($plot->id >= 0){
        $stmt = $this->sqlSavePlotById;
        $stmt->bind_param('isiisssss', $plot->id, $plot->levelName, $plot->X, $plot->Z, $plot->name, $plot->owner, $helpers, $denied, $plot->biome);
    } else{
        $stmt = $this->sqlSavePlot;
        $stmt->bind_param('siisiisssss', $plot->levelName, $plot->X, $plot->Z, $plot->levelName, $plot->X, $plot->Z, $plot->name, $plot->owner, $helpers, $denied, $plot->biome);
    }
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $this->lastSave = time();

    if ($result === false){
        $this->plugin->getLogger()->error($stmt->error);
        return false;
    }
    $this->cachePlot($plot);
    return true;
}
```

The fixed up query:

```
    $this->sqlSavePlot = $this->db->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO plots (`id`, `level`, `X`, `Z`, `name`, `owner`, `helpers`, `denied`, `biome`)
VALUES((SELECT id
FROM plots p
WHERE p.level = ? AND X = ? AND Z = ?),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE name = VALUES(name),
           owner = VALUES(owner),
           helpers = VALUES(helpers),
           denied = VALUES(denied),
           biome = VALUES(biome);"
    );
    $this->sqlSavePlotById = $this->db->prepare(
        "UPDATE plots SET id = ?, level = ?, X = ?, Z = ?, name = ?, owner = ?, helpers = ?, denied = ?, biome = ? WHERE id = VALUES(id);"
    );
```

Thanks alot to everyone! Hope this helps others in the future!